# how to read data from .properties file into .robot file using python(robot framework)

Tags: python, robotframework

**Trying to fetch data from properties file into robot script using python.
we are using robotframework in pycharm.**

Comment: Please provide more details, what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: we need to pass Global variables through Properties file into the robot script. We need Code for the same.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand from the chapter in the user guide on [variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files)?

Answer (score 1):

Robot framework doesn't support properties file. You can process the propperty file and convert it to variable file. Algorithm might be 
 1. Read the property file in python  (Use https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/)
 2. Create a new robot variable file (refer: https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html) 
 3.Traverse through the property file using jproperties library
 3. Write the property key and value in robot variable file
 4. Use the variable file for further test execution